# How to publish SCSS package properly for Javascript projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass

I have a `color.scss` and `main.scss` file as below

```
//color.scss
$special-blue: #0000ff;

:export {
  testBlue: $special-blue;
}

//main.scss
@import 'src/colors';
```

And by having the above setup, using `webpack` to create CSS via couple of webpack-loaders such as `css-modules-typescript-loader, css-loader, postcss-loader, sass-loader`. Once the webpack compilation done, I will get the bundled CSS together with `main.scss.d.ts` with the following content

```
interface CssExports {
  'testBlue': string;
}
export const cssExports: CssExports;
export default cssExports;
```

Then what I've done was published NPM package, consist of `main.scss`, `bundled.css` & `main.scss.d.ts`. When I import the package into my React project, and running the project, I am hitting error

> Failed to compile.
> SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: src/color.scss on line 1 of xxxxxx/main.scss

From the look of it, it seems like I can't just copy only `main.scss`, but I need to copy the entire SCSS source code, just so that I can reference SCSS variables?

Wondering if there is any alternative solution?